# Why complexity function was removed in Sonar 6.7?

Tags: sonarqube, cyclomatic-complexity

In the release note:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10930&version=13972

...show it as "Clean up complexity metrics"

...at Jira, just removed it but don't explain why.
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8331

Anybody know about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total Cyclomatic Complexity is still available but yes, the other Cyclomatic Complexity-related metrics have been removed.

The "why" of that is that there doesn't appear to be a lot of utility in complexity averages. Does a low average mean low overall complexity, or that the highly complex methods are "balanced" by lots of plain-old getters and setters? Conversely, what does having a high average complexity *mean*?

Comment: Sorry for the time without answer. And thanks for the explanation